# Custom UISegmentControl with images inside

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Can I create a custom UISegmentControl which contains images inside like this ? Please take a look on invitation tab.

[image: custom uisegmentcontrol]

Note: I am using objective-c, xcode7.2, ios9.1

Comment: I guess the image itself is a proof that it is possible to create custom segment like in image.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [UISegmentControl class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:), you can use the method:

```
    - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```